# comparing mysql dates using timestamps

Tags: php, mysql

I am using code like this to capture time related records.

Here is a sql fragment ...

```
$SQL_p .= " and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(".$data['task_filter'].") >= " . 
          strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data['datepicker'].' 00:00:00'))));
$SQL_p .= " and UNIX_TIMESTAMP(".$data['task_filter'].") <= " . 
          strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime(str_replace('/','-',$data['datepicker2'].' 23:59:59'))));
```

Dates are entered using the format `dd/mm/YYYY` and converted using `str_replace('/','-',$data['datepicker2'])` where `$data['datepicker2']` is the var holding the date

Using php5 on the command line for testing, when I enter ....

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime(str_replace('/','-','25/11/2011 00:00:00')));
```

I get `2011-11-25 12:00:00` BUT what I expect is `2011-11-25 00:00:00`

Also

```
echo date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime(str_replace('/','-','25/11/2011 23:59:59')));
```

returns `2011-11-25 11:59:59` NOT the expected `2011-11-25 23:59:59`.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime(str_replace('/','-','25/11/2011 00:00:00')));
```

The "h" means 12 hour format, "H" means 24 hour format

Comment: Glad to help - can you accept the answer if you're happy with it?